# SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2014

I get this error:

> Msg 4902, Level 16, State 1, Line 62
>   Cannot find the object "tblDepartment" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

when trying to run this SQL statement:

```
 create table tblDepartment 
 (
      depNum char(5) not null,
      depName varchar(20),
      mgrSSN char(5),
      mgrAssDate char(5)
 )
```

Comment: Your error message has nothing to do with the code you have provided.  The code is to create the table whereas the error message refers to a script that references the table.

Comment: mate,i figure there are nothing happen with my code,the prolem here i didnt Excute the table so there are no tblDepartment here,just try to excute every single table to make sure they were create XD

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code instead

create table dbname.schema.tblDepartment 
 (
      depNum char(5) not null,
      depName varchar(20),
      mgrSSN char(5),
      mgrAssDate char(5)
 )

SELECT *
FROM dbname.schema.tblDepartment.

*Note : Define your dbname and schema so that you can directly select your created table.*